# Is it a good practice to store auth session in the database?

Tags: mysql

I created a login system that in addition to being used on a website, will also be used in mobile applications.

As on cell phones I want to keep the user logged in until he chooses to log out, I did not use the authentication for sessions in PHP.

So I thought it would be better to store the login sessions in the database, for each user request, to verify if the authentication token is still valid.

But I don't know if this is a good practice. Since every time the user updates the screen in the browser, or sends any application request to the system, he will make a query to verify that the login is still active and then make another query to search for what the user requested.

My concern is whether this will become too slow, for a system that could have between 900 million and 1,5 billion users, since the database will have many more requests and verification queries in addition to the normal query requested by the user.

Below is the current structure of my database. I would also like tips if my structure is very wrong.

[image: MysqlDatabase]

Comment: Yes, in fact it could become too taxing your database even for just millions of users.  Have a look at things like JWT (JSON web tokens), which can partially alleviate the need to put strain on your database, by avoiding storing session information there.

Comment: or store sessions in both the database and a key/value store, only periodically updating the database.  you say a billion users, but how many of those would have an active session?

Comment: Get your application working. Spend your time making it do great things for your users, not worrying about how it will perform at global scale. When you get to millions of users you'll have the money and experience to improve performance.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen JWT is irrelevant to my project. In any case, I need to control user authentication from the server-side. Because the same user can connect on several different devices and for security, my control panel can disconnect the user from any device if necessary. And JWT only works just like a more secure cookie. That's why in my table of sessions as shown in the graph above, you have options for devices and last visit on each device. These are data that I should not store in JWT.

Comment: Who says you can't/should not store such information inside a JWT?

Comment: @ysth Sorry, I didn't understand your answer. Could you explain more about what you mean by "only periodically updating the database"? I didn't understand how it would work according to your idea. And I believe that more than 70% of users will be active. It is an application that will have almost the same rhythm as a social network.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm saying, because it is information that must be used by an internal server control. The JWT as far as I understand is information that must be stored on the user's side, just like a cookie. So anyway I need to have some storage on the server-side with some logon data to support administrators. Do you understand what I mean? It is more to have security control if a user's device is compromised, our administrators can log out remotely. How could I invalidate a user's login without having server-side storage?

Comment: @O.Jones I can't, it needs to be resolved now.

Comment: @FernandoVR There are still ways to invalidate a user session with JWT.  You can maintain a blacklist cache which keeps track of revoked tokens.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen And how would I know which token should be blacklisted? If for example, the user calls my company's support saying that one of their devices has been stolen, how can I know which token to block if I don't have any server-side storage? If there is a way to do this with JWT could you give me an example? Because I still can't see a solution that JWT would solve without a server-side registration.

Comment: Again: `You can maintain a blacklist cache` ... Just keep a small cache of tokens which you want to override.  If you use something like Redis, it should be pretty fast to lookup, and also since most users would not be blacklisted, it won't take up much memory.  Eventually, tokens all expire, so you don't need to do any cleanup either, most likely.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't think you understand what I mean yet.  Or I not understand you and I don't see your suggestion as a solution. See the link below, where it says "You cannot invalidate individual JWT tokens", explains a little about what I am thinking. http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/ 
And this other link also tells a little about the problems of JWT. http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/19/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions-part-2-why-your-solution-doesnt-work/ Am I getting it all wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's a good practice to store session information in an application's main transactional database. A great many web applications work this way at large scale.

If you have the skills to do so, you might consider setting things up so session information is stored in a separate database that's not dependent on data in your transactional database. This separate database needs just one table:

```
 login_token   PK
 key           PK
 value
```

The session_id is the value of the login_token session cookie, a large hard-to-guess random value your web app sends to each logged-in user's browser.  For example, if my user id were 100054 the session table might contain these rows for me.

```
 2EwZzPJdigVlrwtkFC5qoe97YE0EBddJ user_id    10054
 2EwZzPJdigVlrwtkFC5qoe97YE0EBddJ user_name  ojones
```

Why use this key/value design? It is easily ported to a high-performance key/value storage system like Redis. It's simple. And, to log me off and kill my session all you need is

```
     DELETE FROM session WHERE login_token = '2EwZzPJdigVlrwtkFC5qoe97YE0EBddJ'
```

(You asked for feedback on your table design. Here is mine: Use INT or BIGINT values for primary keys in tables you expect to become large. VARCHAR values are a poor choice for primary keys because index lookup and row insertion are substantially slower. CHAR(n) values are a slightly better choice, but still slower than integers. The `session` table only covers presently logged in users.)

And, I'll repeat my comment.  Don't waste too much time today on designing your new system so it can run at the scale of Twitter or Facebook (~ 10**9 users). At this stage of your project, you cannot know where your performance bottlenecks will lie when you run at that scale. And it will take you a decade, at the very least, to get that many users. By then you'll have hundreds of developers working on your system. If you hire them wisely, most of them will be smarter than you.

How do I know these things?  Experience, wasted time, and systems that did not scale up even when I designed them to do that.

Comment: Thank you for the tips.About INT and BIGINT in the primary keys, I can't use it, because the primary keys contain letters in addition to numbers. I was told to switch to BINARY or VARBINARY, what is your opinion on that? And about wasting time designing, I don't have many options. This project will be launched to an audience that is already waiting for its launch, and could reach 900 million users in 1 week. I can't risk having problems logging in to your launch. Only after that will I be able to hire someone to solve the problems, but if I make mistakes at first it will be a disaster.

Comment: You can use `BINARY` or `VARBINARY` columns. Or, you can set the collation on the key columns to a `_binary` collation.

Comment: Ramping from 0 - 0.9 gigausers in one week?  mmmkay.

Comment: Thank you. I will study a little more about collations. Yes, about 9 million in the first week, and up to 2 billion in total. I have no way of explaining this so that you can understand.